# How to return in PHP, if row was updated using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am using following query/piece of code, for updating a MySQL database via PHP -

```
$sql = "UPDATE test_table SET lastname='ram' where id=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
echo $result;
```

the problem with this is, the PHP output is `1` even if there was no updating done. 
for e.g. in my case, there is no row that contains `id=1` so when I run this query in phpmyadmin it says `0 rows affected`, while the using the same query in PHP is returning `1`.

**My question is - how to know, if the update was done (`$result = 1`) or not (`$result = 0`) without using a new select query to check the change?**

Comment: First - migrate to more up-to-date API. If not - read manual and find `mysql_affected_rows` or `mysql_info`.

Comment: @u_mulder sorry sir, i am not even a computer student, I am a medical doctor who wanted to learn something other than human body in free time.. that's why I asked this stupid question.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything? As a medical doctor you should be more than capable of doing your own research. And what he indicated was that you shouldn't be using the mysql_ APIs anymore.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes sir I agree with you and u_mulder, that's why I upvoted him too. But there is a limit for doing research. If it's a case of any surgery I would be far too much happy to read 100s of Medical Books. But time does not allow me learn every programming language., like I spend time to learn to do surgery. That's why I asked this question on stacksoverflow

Comment: If you're spending the time to learn PHP and MySQL, then *find a newer resource* that teaches you the mysqli or PDO APIs. People who refuse to heed the warnings of experienced developers are the ones who contribute to the overall insecurity of the Internet. If you have the time to learn, you have the time to lean *right*.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes sir. it's in my todo list. i will learn it as soon as i get some free time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query` returns `true` when an update succeeds (i.e., runs without an error, regardless of how many rows it did or did not update). If you want the number of rows you've actually updated, you need to call [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php):

```
$sql = "UPDATE test_table SET lastname='ram' where id=1";
if (mysql_query($sql)) {
    $result = mysql_affected_rows();
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, works perfect. I will accept it as answer, as soon as time limit of stackoverflow for accepting answer allows me to.

Comment: @Mureinik And shame on you for not even mentioning in your answer that the APIs you are describing have been obsolete for some time now.